# SQL manager if statements and try/catch statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Right now i have 3 if statements below pretty much all the same and i have been looking for a way to combine all 3 so they are not 3 seperate if statements for quite awhile if anyone has any advice on how to proceed i would appreciate it alot. why cant you put else if in sql err

```
  IF (@updateTerm = 1)
  BEGIN
    update odb.transcriptCourse
    set startTerm = 1, endTerm = 1, actualTerm = 1, calendarTerms = 1
    where endyear = @fiscalYear
        and actualTerm = 2
        and schoolNumber in('0150', '0840', '0360')
        and (startTerm != 1 or  endTerm != 1 or actualTerm != 1 or 
    calendarTerms != 1)   END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'This is not term 1';
  END

  IF (@updateTerm = 2)
  BEGIN
    update odb.transcriptCourse
    set startTerm = 2, endTerm = 2, actualTerm = 2, calendarTerms = 2
    where endyear = @fiscalYear
       and actualTerm = 4
       and schoolNumber in('0150', '0840', '0360')
       and (startTerm != 2 or  endTerm != 2 or actualTerm != 2 or 
    calendarTerms != 2)   END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'This is not term 2';
  END

  IF (@updateTerm = 7)
  BEGIN
    update odb.transcriptCourse
    set startTerm = 7, endTerm = 7, actualTerm = 7, calendarTerms = 1
    where endyear = @fiscalYear
        and schoolname like 'Z %'
        and (startTerm != 7 or  endTerm != 7 or actualTerm != 7 or 
    calendarTerms != 1)END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'This is not term 7';
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update odb.transcriptCourse
set startTerm = @updateTerm, endTerm =  @updateTerm, actualTerm =  @updateTerm, calendarTerms = case WHEN @updateTerms = 7 then 1 else @updateTerms end
where  1 = 1 AND (
(@updateTerm = 1 AND (endyear = @fiscalYear
and actualTerm = 2
and schoolNumber in('0150', '0840', '0360')
and (startTerm != 1 or  endTerm != 1 or actualTerm != 1 or 
calendarTerms != 1))  )
OR
( @updateTerm = 2 AND ( endyear = @fiscalYear
and actualTerm = 4
and schoolNumber in('0150', '0840', '0360')
and (startTerm != 2 or  endTerm != 2 or actualTerm != 2 or 
calendarTerms != 2)))
OR
(@updateTerm =3 AND (where endyear = @fiscalYear
and schoolname like 'Z %'
and (startTerm != 7 or  endTerm != 7 or actualTerm != 7 or 
calendarTerms != 1))))
```

The short circuit logic ov `@updateterm = x` will handle the seperate `if` statements

Comment: You missed `SET ... calendarTerms = CASE WHEN @updateTerm = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!